# Need to construct a message response as table and publish to SNS via python

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Hi I'm new to python and I'm trying to compare two tables and get the report on cidr and have to send the report to emails using SNS topic, below is the code I've written.

I'm able to get the report and while publish a message I'm getting validation error any suggestion how to proceed and is there any way I can send a message as table like below.

code:

```
import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
client = boto3.client('sns')


dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table = dynamodb.Table('cidr')
cidr_atd = dynamodb.Table('cidr_allocated')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    main_cdr = table.scan()
    sub_cdr = cidr_atd.scan()
    regions = {}
    
    for cdr in main_cdr['Items']:
        regions[cdr['region']] = {}
        regions[cdr['region']]['provider'] = cdr['provider']
        regions[cdr['region']]['subnet'] = cdr['subnet'].split('/')[1]
        regions[cdr['region']]['cidravaliable'] = [i for i in range(int(regions[cdr['region']]['subnet']), 33)]
    
    # for key, val in regions.items():
        # print(key, ' subnet_missing : ', val['subnet_missing'])
    
    for scdr in sub_cdr['Items']:
        regions[scdr['region']]['cidravaliable'].remove(int(scdr['subnet '].split('/')[1]))
    
    #print('-' * 110)
    #print('| Region' + ' ' * 17 + '| Provider' + ' ' * 5 + '| Remaining CIDRs' + ' ' * 52 + '|')
    #print('-' * 110)
    #for key, val in regions.items():
    #    del regions[key]['subnet']
    #    region = '| ' + key
    #    provider = '| ' + val['provider']
    #    subnet_missing = '| ' + ', '.join(list(map(str, val['subnet_missing'])))
    #    print(region + ' ' * (25 - len(region)) + provider + ' ' * (15 - len(provider)) + subnet_missing + ' ' * (69 - len(subnet_missing)) + '|')
    #print('-' * 110)
    
    
    def publishOntoSNSTopic(regions):

        client.publish(
            TargetArn='arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:333333333:test',
            Message=regions,
            Subject='test'
        )
    
    publishOntoSNSTopic(regions)
    

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(regions)
    }
```

response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Message, value: {'us-west-2': {'provider': 'aws', 'cidravaliable': [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]}, 'centralus': {'provider': 'azure', 'cidravaliable': [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]}, 'eu-west-1': {'provider': 'aws', 'cidravaliable': [22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]}, 'ap-southeast-1': {'provider': 'aws', 'cidravaliable': [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]}, 'eu-west-2': {'provider': 'aws', 'cidravaliable': [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]}, 'eu-central-1': {'provider': 'aws', 'cidravaliable': [19, 21, 23, 24, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]}}, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'str'>",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 51, in lambda_handler\n    publishOntoSNSTopic(regions)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 45, in publishOntoSNSTopic\n    client.publish(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 316, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 607, in _make_api_call\n    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 655, in _convert_to_request_dict\n    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py\", line 297, in serialize_to_request\n    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())\n"
```

message I'm trying to construct instead of json:

```
Function logs:
START RequestId: 21b40036-a590-4854-ac5b-2b23bff56ecd Version: $LATEST
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Region                 | Provider     | Remaining CIDRs                                                    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| us-west-2              | aws          | 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32                         |
| centralus              | azure        | 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32                 |
| eu-west-1              | aws          | 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32                             |
| ap-southeast-1         | aws          | 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32             |
| eu-west-2              | aws          | 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32             |
| eu-central-1           | aws          | 19, 21, 23, 24, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32                             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: drive-by comment: you are sending a dict but it should be a string may be `json.dumps`

Comment: Able to achieve  this using jinja2 template with HTML response.